# Error in foreach loop PHP JSON

Tags: php, json, parsing, foreach

I am trying to parse json file in php. But am getting error in `foreach`. This is my php code.

```
{
    "movies": 
    [
{
    "title": "Aarilirunthu Arubathu Varai",
    "year": "1979",
    "genre": "Drama",
    "starting": "Rajinikanth",
},

{
    "title": "Vinnaithandi varuvaya",
    "year": "2010",
    "genre": "Love",
    "starting": "Simbu",
},

{
    "title": "The Pursuit of happyness",
    "year": "2006",
    "genre": "Biography",
    "starting": "Willsmith",
},

{
    "title": "Marly and Me",
    "year": "2008",
    "genre": "Comedy and drama",
    "starting": "Owen wilson",
},

{
    "title": "Hachi: A Dog's Tale",
    "year": "2009",
    "genre": "Loyalty",
    "starting": "Hachi",
},

{
    "title": "Maalai pozhudin mayakathilay",
    "year": "2013",
    "genre": "Love",
    "starting": "Aari",
},


    ]
}
<?php
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("movies.json");
    $json = json_decode($jsondata,true);
    $output ="<ul>";
    foreach($json ['movies'] as $movies)
    {
    $output .= "<h4>".$movies['title']."</h4>";
    $output .="<li>Year: ".$movies['year']."</li>";
    $output .="<li>Genre: ".$movies['genre']."</li>";
    $output .="<li>Starting: ".$movies['starting']."</li>";
    }
    $output .="</ul>";
    echo $output ;
?>
```

Can someone help me to find out the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And whats the error message?

Comment: That JSON has an invalid format :) Remove the extra commas after  the last elements of each sub object

Comment: And after that, here you go : https://eval.in/187510 :P

Comment: thank u. i will do it and come back.

Comment: the error message is, Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: am getting output like,                                           "; foreach($json ['movies'] as $movies) { $output .= "
".$movies['title']."
"; $output .="
Year: ".$movies['year']."
"; $output .="
Genre: ".$movies['genre']."
"; $output .="
Starting: ".$movies['starting']."
"; } $output .=""; echo $output ; ?>

Answer (score 3):

Remove all unwanted commas , they are not allowed in JSON,

```
  {
      "movies": 
      [
  {
      "title": "Aarilirunthu Arubathu Varai",
      "year": "1979",
      "genre": "Drama",
      "starting": "Rajinikanth"
  },

  {
      "title": "Vinnaithandi varuvaya",
      "year": "2010",
      "genre": "Love",
      "starting": "Simbu"
  },

  {
      "title": "The Pursuit of happyness",
      "year": "2006",
      "genre": "Biography",
      "starting": "Willsmith"
  },

  {
      "title": "Marly and Me",
      "year": "2008",
      "genre": "Comedy and drama",
      "starting": "Owen wilson"
  },

  {
      "title": "Hachi: A Dog's Tale",
      "year": "2009",
      "genre": "Loyalty",
      "starting": "Hachi"
  },

  {
      "title": "Maalai pozhudin mayakathilay",
      "year": "2013",
      "genre": "Love",
      "starting": "Aari"
  }


      ]
  }
```

Comment: even though i removed a all the unwanted commas as u said, am getting the same error like, --->Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: There is no error on my system, you may want to chack **file_get_contents** function, make sure it's getting correct file and data.